# Logout problem!

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

I have some 30 jsp pages with login and logout. I have put all the pages in the Session, so that only valid user can have access. Now the problem is, whenever user hits the logout the session gets invalidated but if the user presses the back button of the browser still it displays the secured pages (which shouldn't get displayed).

I got to know that the problem was with the browser which holds the cache and history. So I applied `response.setheader("cache-control",.....)` etc. on secured pages and also `window.history.go(+1)` in the body of secured pages.

It works fine to some extent but once in a while it displays the secured pages. And also once the user logs in session starts and when he will be inside the website, back button should work for him without any hassle (without prompting the user to resend the form data). Once he logs out the session should end and he should not be able to access the pages anymore by hitting back button. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Making something secure is not same as making it invisible

Comment: @ralu, +1.  @Mahesh, you are confusing security (i.e. the whole stuff about sessions) with whether the user can "see" the past page.  It has nothing to do with caching, which really controls whether the browser can avoid visiting your site in the first place and just serve your user the "last" page he sees.  All these do not have anyting to do with whether the user can do anything useful with your site after he is logged out.

Answer (score 5):

**1** For checking if the user is authenticated don't use code on jsp , We have [`Filter`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html) for that only make use of it.

**2** Make your [`Filter`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html) to do following to resolve caching issue

```
HttpServletResponse hsr = (HttpServletResponse) response;
hsr.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
hsr.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
hsr.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

**3** Remove javascript

Comment: @Jigar: This doesn't work in my case. Could you extend a bit,'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32561045/how-to-prevent-caching-of-pages-in-spring-mvc/32561452#32561452'